# How to set the locale for Devise in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-i18n

Currently I use this code as suggested by the Rails guide:

```
  # application_controller.rb

  around_action :switch_locale
  def switch_locale(&action)
    locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
  end
```

This is **thread safe** and works perfectly for the application... but not for Devise! Devise keeps using the default language (even if the translated YML files are present).

What should I do in order to tell Devise the language for the current user?

I know that there is `I18n.locale` but it is not thread safe...

Comment: Did you use `devise-i18n` (https://github.com/tigrish/devise-i18n) gem?

Comment: @RifatulIslamChayon I have also tried to install that gem, but doesn't solve the problem. That gem is only to provide the translated views. My issue is to set the locale for Devise for each request.